# VBA - Identify and Copy Row from .txt file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following code to go line by line through a txt file and (1) identify a text string and (2) import the following 50 digits.  I'd like to find a way to import the entire ROW from the txt file but am unsure the code.  Also, is there a way to tell VBA to find the SECOND or THIRD string in the txt file?  Currently the code below is simply locating the first occurrence.  Thank you!!

```
Sub CopyTXT()

myFile = "G:\Filings\Test\Test.txt"
Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    Text = Text & textline
Loop

Close #1

Revenue = InStr(Text, "Operating Revenues")

 'This is where I'm confused - not sure how to copy that row, so I simply pick a large value and use a mid formula - would like to change this.
Range("H1").Value = Mid(Text, Revenue + 7, 50)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (assuming the text you're looking for is on a single line and not split across lines)

```
Sub CopyTXT()

    Dim myFile, textline
    Dim i As Long

    i = 0
    myFile = "G:\Filings\Test\Test.txt"

    Open myFile For Input As #1

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline

        If InStr(textline, "Operating Revenues") > 0 Then
            i = i + 1

            If i = 2 Then
                Range("H1").Value = textline
            End If

        End If

    Loop

    Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @tim.  Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for - to address the other question - is there code to make VBA look for the SECOND or THIRD occurrence of the text string?